# Body onload creates blank page

Tags: javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts

I am trying to display the last three months in a dropdown. I created a JavaScript function and called it in the body element's `Onload` attribute, but I am getting a blank page with no errors in the log.

Below is the JSP:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Collection" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/displaytag-12.tld" prefix="display"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> 

<%@page buffer="16kb"%>


<script type="text/javascript">
function addOption(selectbox,text,value )
{
    var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
    optn.text = text;
    optn.value = value;
    selectbox.options.appendChild(optn);
}

function OnloadPage()
{
    alert('Here');
    var date=new Date();
    addOption(document.forms[0].month,date.getMonth(),date.getMonth());
    addOption(document.forms[0].month,date.getMonth()-1,date.getMonth()-1);
    addOption(document.forms[0].month,date.getMonth()-2,date.getMonth()-2);
    }
</script>
<TABLE class="ReportFilter">

        <TR>
            <TD colspan="2">&nbsp;</TD>
        </TR>
</TABLE>
<body onload="OnloadPage()">
<html:form action="/zeroScoreReport.do">

<html:select property="month" name ="month" style="width:175;">
    <html:option value="-1">--Please Select--</html:option>
</html:select>
    <display:table name="scoreCardCol" pagesize="20" sort="list" id="data" requestURI="" class="tablelist" export="true">
            <display:setProperty name="export.csv" value="false"/>
        <display:setProperty name="export.xml" value="false"/>
        <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename">ZeroDefectScoreCard.xls</display:setProperty>

            <display:column title="ZONE" property="zone" /> 
            <display:column title="TM OPS NAME" sortable="true" property="tm_ops_name"></display:column>
            <display:column title="RPCT BRANCH CODE" sortable="true" property="rcpt_branch_code"></display:column>
            <display:column title="SUM TOT APP" sortable="true" property="sum_totapp"></display:column>
            <display:column title="SUM ERROR APP" sortable="true" property="sum_error_app"></display:column>
            <display:column title="SUM ZERO DEF APP" sortable="true" property="sum_zero_def_app"></display:column>

    </display:table>
</html:form>
```

Edit: After changing some code, now I am getting the error below in the log:

```
ServletException in '/jsp/zero/frm_ZeroScoreCard.jsp': javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean under name month
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /jsp/zero/frm_ZeroScoreCard.jsp at line 38
```

Despite adding in the form bean:

```
private String month="";
public String getMonth() {
        return month;
    }
    public void setMonth(String month) {
        this.month = month;
    }
```

Comment: i think you should add the name="month"

Comment: added name ="month",still getting blank page.

Comment: shouldnt `option` be `html:option`?!

Comment: so you mean I should change "var optn = document.createElement("OPTION"); " to var optn = document.createElement("HTML:OPTION"); ???

Comment: i search google you should too i dont know struts actually i only read intro chapter but i saw it on a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` attribute in `<html:select>` should be name of the `formbean` and to refer it in javascript,should use `styleId`.

so the code looks like

```
<html:select styleId="monthh" property="monthh" name ="initiationfrm" style="width:175;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `add` to `appendChild` here:

```
selectbox.options.add(optn);
```

So it should be:

```
selectbox.options.appendChild(optn);
```

Comment: @alfasin: You are welcome, also as @shareef told, I dont see `name="month"` for your select box.

Comment: changed to appendChild,still getting blank page.

Comment: @happy:  Do you see the alert on page load ?

Comment: No,I dont even get that alert.

Comment: @happy: There is some other problem then i suspect

Comment: After changing I get,javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean under name month .Please see updated post.

Comment: @happy: Yes so your actual problem is not with JS now, it is with Java code

Answer (score 0):

add `<script type="text/javascript">` instead of `<script>`

might be different many errors like html tag is not used in your page 
please provide full JSP  to check and the browser you test on

Comment: i think you should provide all jsp code to detect possible errors check `<html>` tag

Comment: getting Cannot find bean under name month